# carouFredSel stop on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a site based on the mist HTML template, and I want the caroufredsel plugin to stop when the mouse is hovering it.

The site is:
http://deimos.dlya.com.uy/developers2/index.html

The carousel is on the "API's" section.

I've managed to make it autoplay so far by using this line of code:

```html
<div class="carousel-box white no-style overflow no-pagination" data-carousel-autoplay="true">
```

Anyone knows if this can be done by using one of the "data-carousel" variables? I've tried stoponhover and autohover with no luck.